# .NET Custom inherited attributes

Tags: .net, reflection, attributes, custom-attributes

I created a custom attribute with `Inherited = true` and `AllowMultiple = true`. Then I use `GetCustomAttributes` method to retrieve custom attributes, include inherited attributes.

My question is: While iterating over array of custom attributes that found by `GetCustomAttributes`, is it possible to know if specific attribute instance is inherited or it is types "direct" attribute?

Comment: Reflection does not give you a hard time to check if Type.BaseType also has the attribute.  Just a weenie while loop.

Comment: Yeah, right, forgot about the loop option...thanks :)